# How to visualize mean edit distance in Tensorboard using Keras callback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, tensorboard

So far, I have been experimenting with Tensorflow and Keras. I took a code from [image_ocr.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) which allowed me to train printed text ocr. I want to see the training progress as it goes and have successfuly visualized the accuracy and loss of the training model. However, from what I have heard OCR RNN does not take accuracy as a validation but using mean edit distance instead to validate the accuracy of the words. In this case, I have been trying to get a variable called **mean_ed** and **mean_norm_ed** to be visualized in Tensorboard from class ***VizCallback***. I have tried the method from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285501/how-can-i-create-a-custom-callback-in-keras) but it still does not work. Can anyone help me with visualizing the mean edit distance variables? Here are the code snippets from my code:

```
class VizCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

def __init__(self, run_name, test_func, text_img_gen, num_display_words=6):
    self.test_func = test_func
    self.output_dir = os.path.join(
        OUTPUT_DIR, run_name)
    self.text_img_gen = text_img_gen
    self.num_display_words = num_display_words
    if not os.path.exists(self.output_dir):
        os.makedirs(self.output_dir)

def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.med = []
    self.nmed = []

def show_edit_distance(self, num, logs={}):
    num_left = num
    mean_norm_ed = 0.0
    mean_ed = 0.0
    while num_left > 0:
        word_batch = next(self.text_img_gen)[0]
        num_proc = min(word_batch['the_input'].shape[0], num_left)
        decoded_res = decode_batch(self.test_func, word_batch['the_input'][0:num_proc])
        for j in range(num_proc):
            edit_dist = editdistance.eval(decoded_res[j], word_batch['source_str'][j])
            mean_ed += float(edit_dist)
            mean_norm_ed += float(edit_dist) / len(word_batch['source_str'][j])
        num_left -= num_proc
    mean_norm_ed = mean_norm_ed / num
    mean_ed = mean_ed / num
    #Create scalar summaries for both mean edit distance and normalized mean edit distance
    tf_med_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None,name='med_summary')
    tf_nmed_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None,name='nmed_summary')
    tf_med = tf.summary.scalar('med', tf_med_ph)
    tf_nmed = tf.summary.scalar('nmed', tf_nmed_ph)
    performance_summaries = tf.summary.merge([tf_med,tf_nmed])

    #Create a session for displaying the summary
    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
    summ_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join('summaries','first'), session.graph)

    # Execute the summaries defined above
    summ = session.run(performance_summaries, feed_dict={tf_med_ph:mean_ed, tf_nmed_ph:mean_norm_ed})

    # Write the obtained summaries to the file, so it can be displayed in the TensorBoard
    summ_writer.add_summary(summ, epoch)

    session.close()
    print('\nOut of %d samples:  Mean edit distance: %.3f Mean normalized edit distance: %0.3f'
          % (num, mean_ed, mean_norm_ed))

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    self.model.save_weights(os.path.join(self.output_dir, 'weights%02d.h5' % (epoch)))
    self.show_edit_distance(256)
    word_batch = next(self.text_img_gen)[0]
    res = decode_batch(self.test_func, word_batch['the_input'][0:self.num_display_words])
    if word_batch['the_input'][0].shape[0] < 256:
        cols = 2
    else:
        cols = 1
    for i in range(self.num_display_words):
        plt.subplot(self.num_display_words // cols, cols, i + 1)
        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            the_input = word_batch['the_input'][i, 0, :, :]
        else:
            the_input = word_batch['the_input'][i, :, :, 0]
        plt.imshow(the_input.T, cmap='Greys_r')
        plt.xlabel('Truth = \'%s\'\nDecoded = \'%s\'' % (word_batch['source_str'][i], res[i]))
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 13)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(self.output_dir, 'e%02d.png' % (epoch)))
    plt.close()

def train(run_name, start_epoch, stop_epoch, img_w):
# Input Parameters
img_h = 64
words_per_epoch = 16000
val_split = 0.2
val_words = int(words_per_epoch * (val_split))

# Network parameters
conv_filters = 16
kernel_size = (3, 3)
pool_size = 2
time_dense_size = 32
rnn_size = 512
minibatch_size = 32

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_w, img_h)
else:
    input_shape = (img_w, img_h, 1)

fdir = os.path.dirname(get_file('wordlists.tgz',
                                origin='http://test.com/wordlist.tgz', untar=True))

img_gen = TextImageGenerator(monogram_file=os.path.join(fdir, 'wordlist_mono_clean.txt'),
                             bigram_file=os.path.join(fdir, 'wordlist_bi_clean.txt'),
                             minibatch_size=minibatch_size,
                             img_w=img_w,
                             img_h=img_h,
                             downsample_factor=(pool_size ** 2),
                             val_split=words_per_epoch - val_words
                             )
act = 'relu'
input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
               activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
               name='conv1')(input_data)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max1')(inner)
inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
               activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
               name='conv2')(inner)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max2')(inner)

conv_to_rnn_dims = (img_w // (pool_size ** 2), (img_h // (pool_size ** 2)) * conv_filters)
inner = Reshape(target_shape=conv_to_rnn_dims, name='reshape')(inner)

# cuts down input size going into RNN:
inner = Dense(time_dense_size, activation=act, name='dense1')(inner)

# Two layers of bidirectional GRUs
# GRU seems to work as well, if not better than LSTM:

gru_1 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(inner)
gru_1b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(inner)
gru1_merged = add([gru_1, gru_1b])
gru_2 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
gru_2b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)

# transforms RNN output to character activations:
inner = Dense(img_gen.get_output_size(), kernel_initializer='he_normal',
              name='dense2')(concatenate([gru_2, gru_2b]))
y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)
Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=y_pred).summary()

labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[img_gen.absolute_max_string_len], dtype='float32')
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
# Keras doesn't currently support loss funcs with extra parameters
# so CTC loss is implemented in a lambda layer
loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])

# clipnorm seems to speeds up convergence
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=5)

model = Model(inputs=[input_data, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)

#Make tensorboard instance
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
tbname="tensorboard-of-{}".format(int(time.time()))
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
log_dir="logs/{}".format(tbname),
histogram_freq=0,
write_images=True)

# the loss calc occurs elsewhere, so use a dummy lambda func for the loss
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
if start_epoch > 0:
    weight_file = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, os.path.join(run_name, 'weights%02d.h5' % (start_epoch - 1)))
    model.load_weights(weight_file)
# captures output of softmax so we can decode the output during visualization
test_func = K.function([input_data], [y_pred])

viz_cb = VizCallback(run_name, test_func, img_gen.next_val())

model.fit_generator(generator=img_gen.next_train(),
                    steps_per_epoch=(words_per_epoch - val_words) // minibatch_size,
                    epochs=stop_epoch,
                    validation_data=img_gen.next_val(),
                    validation_steps=val_words // minibatch_size,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard,viz_cb, img_gen],
                    initial_epoch=start_epoch)
```

Any help would be much appriciated. Thank you!

**P.S.** I am using Tensorflow 1.9.0 and Python 3.6.8

**UPDATE**
now it is just a matter of passing the variable performance_summaries from the VizCallbak class towards the metrics in the train function. Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify `show_edit_distance` to add the summaries every time this function is being called:

```
def show_edit_distance(self, num, epoch):
    ...
    summary = tf.Summary()
    summary.value.add(tag='mean_ed', simple_value=mean_ed)
    summ_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

    summary = tf.Summary()
    summary.value.add(tag='mean_norm_ed', simple_value=mean_norm_ed)
    summ_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
    ...
```

Note that you will need an extra argument `epoch`:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    ...
    self.show_edit_distance(256, epoch)
    ...
```

The Tensorboard callback should automatically pick up these summaries, as they're being added to the `GraphKeys.SUMMARIES` collection.

**NOTE:** Unfortunately, I couldn't test the solution. Please let me know if there is something I am missing.

Comment: I tried your method and it returns a type error since tf.summary.scalar does not have data and step as parameters. What did I do wrong here? TypeError: scalar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'step'

Comment: And also as you can see from my code above, I have tried using tf_med = tf.summary.scalar('med', tf_med_ph) and tf_nmed = tf.summary.scalar('nmed', tf_nmed_ph). Is it because I am missing something important like an import maybe? please let me know, I am still struggling even until now.

Comment: We might be using different TF versions. I've updated my answer. Could you please try this new way?

Comment: By using summ_writer do you mean declaring a new FileWriter variable like so? summ_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join('summaries'), session.graph). If so, this creates a new instance of summary instead of sending it together with the session as you can see in function train(). Is there any way to send the summary to the sess.run instead so that there is no multiple summary?

Comment: Could you try declaring the summary writer outside `show_edit_distance`? I believe it should be declared only once. Also, you should use the same session all the time